# How to show all rows from database to jsp page using struts 2?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I am new in Struts2 and Hibernate. I want to create a drop-down list like the following [ using hibernate and struts] which pops up a menu dynamically and when an id will be selected, it shows all the information of that id:

I tried much to do this. but failed. can anybody help me please:

I have a 'Student' table like this:

```
id  name  age
1...a.....20
2...b.....24
3...c.....22
```

Using Hibernate I create model and dao like... StudentModel and StudentDAO

in DAO, i implement a method which returns the lists of the ids like this:

```
// StudentDAO.java
public List<String> findId(String id) {
    .....
    return ...
}
```

Now, I define action into struts.xml file like this:

```
// Struts.xml
<action name="idSelection" class="..." method="findId">
    <result> studentpage.jsp </result>
</action>
```

so, now how can i implement the studentpage.jsp. Would you please give tell me the necessary code or reference to do this

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your List like that: `List<Student>` studentList, and Student is

```
public class Student {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String age;
    ...
    getter and setter...
}
request.setAttribute("studentList", studentList);
```

You can implement the studentpage.jsp:

```
<table>
<s:iterator value="#request.studentList" status="status">
<tr>
    <td>
        <s:property value="name">
    </td>
    <td>
        <s:property value="age">
    </td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>
```

If you return List like that: `List<List<String>>`, you can do :

```
<table>
<s:iterator value="#request.studentList" status="status" id="list">
<tr>
    <td>
        name:<s:property value="#list[#status.index][1]"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        age:<s:property value="#list[#status.index][2]"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm a beginner. Can you post a complete example here..!

Answer (score 0):

That is **not** the way Struts2 works.

When you call a method, that method must return a String result only. That String result is mapped in your struts.xml to return a specific result (in your case, a JSP).

To access Action data from the JSP, you need to access the Getters of the fields you want to read.
Any IDE out there is able to write the Getters and Setters for you. If you are using Eclipse, <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>R</kbd> will surely help.

Also, like OOP (Object Oriented Programming) suggests, you should use an object to carry / transmit the data, with a method like `findStudents()` (instead of `findIds()` and then making a call for each `id`).

Assuming then a Student object like this

```
public class Student {        
    private Long id; 
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    /* GETTERS (or ACCESSORS) */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /* SETTERS (or MUTATORS) */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

in your Action you should declare a private list of them , with getter/setters of course, and evaluate it in the method called:

```
private List<Student> students;

public List<Student> getStudents(){
    return students;
} 
public void setStudents(List<Students> students){
    this.students = students;
} 

public String findStudents(){
     students = getMyServiceDaoOrSomething().findAllStudents();
     return "success";
}
```

with a config like

```
<action name="students" class="..." method="findStudents">
    <result>studentpage.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Note that `<result>` is equal to `<result name="success">` (it is called Intelligent Default), and when `method` is not specified, the `execute()` method will be executed.

Then in JSP, iterate the result and print each `Student` object at once:

```
<s:iterator value="students">
    <s:hidden name="id" />
    <s:textfield name="name" />
    <s:property value="age" />
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Thanks for you guidelines. But I want to create the output in the following way:

http://theproblemdomains789.blogspot.com/2013/09/drop-down-select-list.html

[sorry, i could not upload the image as my current reputation is below 10]

And when anybody click on 1, it will show results for that id. and in this way.

Comment: I can't see nothing in the site you linked :| By the way, you should stick to what I've written, except the JSP part: that is the View, and it is the only place where the implementations should differs. Mine is an example, just drawn your own JSP and you'll be fine.

Comment: Actually, in that link... i tried to represent what will be the final output to choose the student id. After selecting that Id it will generate all the information of that student

Comment: The image you linked does not exist anymore. There is nothing in your link. [Press CTRL+F5 then look at the image](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-8tmZx-q2dxY/UkBJA61si5I/AAAAAAAAAlQ/pG3TjCwu8k4/s1600/1.png).

Comment: BTW, try to implement it by yourself, 'cause even if you post your image, noone will do the entire job for you. Start setting up Struts correctly and getting the data from the database to the JSP through the Action like described in my answer. Only then you should start modelling it. P.S: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped

Comment: Thank you. I understand the logic from you and now I am implementing using this logic. Thanks for your help.